# Live Share on Visual Studio Code randomly disconnects

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare, live-share

I have an issue with Live Share. Every time I join a session created by another user, I get disconnected after a while, and suddenly I start experiencing Wi-Fi problems. I don't receive any error messages, and after some time, everything returns to normal. This only happens when I join someone else's session and not when I create my own.